# Disks not being mount as read/write

Tags: mount, dvd, read-only

For some reason my dvd isn't being mount as read/write, despite the drive and disk supporting it. I know that this should work because I have written to disks like this before. I can't figure out what I've changed. Here is the output of `sudo lshw -class disk`

```
*-disk                  
   description: ATA Disk
   product: WDC WD10EZEX-00W
   vendor: Western Digital
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: 1A01
   serial: ****************
   size: 931GiB (1TB)
   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
   configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=ac76fd2f-dd87-48b5-aa5a-a705e2393abc logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
*-cdrom
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: CDDVDW SH-216BB
   vendor: hp
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/cdrw
   logical name: /dev/dvd
   logical name: /dev/dvdrw
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   logical name: /media/username/Debian 8.6.0 i386 1
   version: HE50
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready
 *-medium
      physical id: 0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
      logical name: /media/username/Debian 8.6.0 i386 1
      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
      configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 signature=425ed49e state=mounted
```

I realize that under `mount.options` in `*-cdrom` it says `ro`, but I can't figure out how to change that.

Comment: I've never seen a DVD or CD mounted read-write. Writing on them is called "burning" and is not done by simply writing or modifying or deleting files.

Comment: I understand that, but my burning software (brasero), refuses to burn the disk, as well as the OS's format function which refuses to work at all.